# Help - I keep getting banned for no reason

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I had got banned around a week ago for one question which had got downvoted a lot. I had expressed my displeasure at that ban in a previous post on this site. The main issue with the downvoted question is that I hadn't meant to post it (it got posted by accident, or due to a glitch idk) and I didn't get the notification that the question was incomplete until I got banned, and so, didn't get a chance to edit it. Regardless, I got my ban lifted yesterday, so I asked a question and now I've been banned again. Now, the question that I asked after having my ban lifted had three upvotes, so not really 'terribly received'. So either the ban is a glitch or I've been banned twice for the same question. I really have no idea what's going on here

Comment: Have you flagged a moderator on your last question?  If so, please delete this post.  We can't know what happened, and so your best solution, if there is one to be had, is to flag for moderator attention.  Mod's are typically more available in handling flags, so by using the meta site to air your confusion, you waste most users time with matters that we cannot assist you with.

Comment: Yes I certainly did flag for moderator attention for the last question, basically got told to deal with it. Regardless, the more important thing is why I've been banned for one question twice

Comment: No users can really assist you with this.  That's my point.  I appreciate that you took that action (flagging a mod).  I understand your frustration, but non-mods are powerless in any of this, and even mods are powerless.

Comment: Focus most immediately on well-written questions that you think you can answer well.  If you know mathjax well enough, or even if not, perhaps work at it and at suggesting edits.  When they are approved, you get two points per edit.  Focus on what you think you can do do exhibit helpful contributions and earn rep to validate this.  It shouldn't take long, if you consistently do this, to make the one failed post you refer to become rather meaningless in the long run.  But when, and I am sure you can do it, you regain the privilege of asking, make sure to ask them well.

Comment: I hope an extra upvote on your most recent question has helped you move in that direction.

Comment: Or $2$ ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: "Now, the question that I asked after having my ban lifted had three upvotes, so not really 'terribly received'." 3 upvotes is a well received question and so ban doesn't makes sense here. Maybe it's not really 3. For example, sometimes you see 2 upvotes in a question _but_ that doesn't necessarily mean 2 'pure' upvotes, sometimes this means a difference (10 upvotes and 8 downvotes, hence '2 final upvotes'). One way to check if this is the case, is in your rep tab.

Comment: so, if the system saw more downvotes, e.g. 8 downvotes independently of the 10 upvotes, on your question well maybe it decided to ban you again..// just supposing though :)

Comment: @MagicConchShell that question now has 6 upvotes, and no downvotes.  The only other remaining question has 4 upvotes and one downvote.  In any case, MNIShaurya, I am hoping your status has since changed?

Comment: @amWhy It hasnt. But in any case, thank you for your help(and upvotes) :)

Comment: I'd suggest learning to use $\LaTeX$ notation for your posts; see [this brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and its links to further documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mods don't have full access to the internal workings of the autoban system but I think this is because your first question was so heavily downvoted that your current aggregate question score is still negative. I can't undo the ban but I threw another upvote in there for you.

If you keep asking good questions and they continue to be well-received, this won't happen anymore.